# Threads. Doesn't display "END" in log

Tags: java, multithreading

I got 2 classes:
**First class** I invoke Constructor in LogScheduler - is Singleton, constructor create new Thread and start it. Main Thread going sleep on 5 sec, then i set boolean variable false to stop loop:

```
public class Launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LogScheduler log = LogScheduler.getInstance();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        log.setActive(false);

        List<String> logs = log.getLogs();
        logs.add("ABBA");

        log.showLogs();
    }
}
```

**Second class**:

```
public class LogScheduler {

    public static final LogScheduler INSTANCE = new LogScheduler();

    private final List<String> logs = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Thread worker;

    private boolean active = true;

    private int i = 0;

    private LogScheduler() {
        addLog("Launch");
        worker = new Thread(this::log);
        worker.setName(getClass().getName());
        worker.start();
    }

    private void log() {
        addLog("Start");
        while (active) {
            synchronized (worker) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()
                            .getName() + " - " + i++);
                    worker.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        addLog("End");
    }

    public void addLog(String value) {
            logs.add(value);
    }

    public void showLogs() {
        logs.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public List<String> getLogs() {
        return logs;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public static LogScheduler getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Thread getWorker() {
        return worker;
    }
}
```

**Console Out**:

```
job.LogScheduler - 0
job.LogScheduler - 1
job.LogScheduler - 2
job.LogScheduler - 3
job.LogScheduler - 4
Launch
Start
ABBA
```

**'End' - word in log() method doens't display in console.**
Give some advice to fix it please. I try synchronized logs variable and addLog method, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `active` to false, you don't give enough time to the logger to see that change. It is waiting in `worker.wait` he you set active to false, and move on to finish the program.

You have to `notify` the worker when you set active:

```
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    synchronized(worker) {
        this.active = active;
        worker.notify()
    }
}
```

So when you change active, the `worker.wait` is notified.

However, even with this there are executions where the last log will be printed and there are executions where last log will not be printed, because your program may terminate before the worker has a chance to add the last log. You need further synchronization to guarantee that, or you can wait a bit before returning from main.

You do have a data race as well. When you add/read logs you are not synchronizing the access to the shared log list. Either synchronize access to it, or use a synchronized collection to store logs.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `log.getLogs()` the "End" has not been written yet. To illustrate that you can try this main function where i add an other sleep before `log.getLogs()` which will give enought time to write "End" :

```
public class Launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LogScheduler log = LogScheduler.getInstance();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        log.setActive(false);

        //new sleep
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<String> logs = log.getLogs();

        logs.add("ABBA");

        log.showLogs();
    }
}
```